# Strange length error when defining a conjunction in J

Tags: j

I'm playing around with adverbs and conjunctions in J, and have run across a strange problem. I've defined a simple adverb called `persistence` that can be used to view the progression of numbers generated when calculating the digital product or digital sum of a number.

```
S =: 1 : 'u/@:("."0)@":^:a:"0'
```

`+ S 234` gives us `234 9`. I then used this to create another adverb that calculates the persistence of a number.

```
P =: 1 : '<:@#@(u S)"0'
```

`+ P 234` gives us `1`. Now, imagine we want to find all numbers below 30 with additive persistence of 2 and then view the list generated by `S` for each number, e.g.,

```
+ S I. 2 = + P i.30
```

This generates the following list:

```
19 10 1
28 10 1
29 11 2
```

So far, so good. Now, I wanted to take this and turn it into a conjunction, the left-hand side of which contains the verb to use for persistence and the right-hand side of which contains the number used to limit the list. (`2` in the example above.) Here's my definition of that conjunction:

```
Q =: 2 : 'u S I. n = u P'
```

If I enter the expression `+ Q 2` into the J console, I get back the following:

```
+/@:("."0)@":^:a:"0 I. 2 = <:@#@(+/@:("."0)@":^:a:"0)"0
```

This is exactly correct, and if I run the full expression with an argument such as `i.30`, it works fine:

```
+/@:("."0)@":^:a:"0 I. 2 = <:@#@(+/@:("."0)@":^:a:"0)"0 i.30
```

However, when I enter the expression `+ Q 2 i.30` into the J console, I get back a 'length error'. Why?! Isn't `+ Q 2` exactly equivalent to `+/@:("."0)@":^:a:"0 I. 2 = <:@#@(+/@:("."0)@":^:a:"0)"0`?

I'm completely stumped. What am I missing? I've played around with rank both inside the definition of the conjunction and outside of it. I just don't get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+ Q 2` is exactly equivalent to the expression you provided, but when using it in an expression it is as if it is in parenthesis.

```
   +/@:("."0)@":^:a:"0 I. 2 = <:@#@(+/@:("."0)@":^:a:"0)"0 i.30
19 10 1
28 10 1
29 11 2
   (+/@:("."0)@":^:a:"0 I. 2 = <:@#@(+/@:("."0)@":^:a:"0)"0) i.30
|length error
```

In general `f g h y` != `(f g h) y`. In the latter `f g h` defines a [train](http://jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dictf.htm). For example:

```
   avg=: +/ % #
   +/ % # 1 2 3
0.333333
   (+/ % #) 1 2 3
2
   avg 1 2 3
2
```

You can fix your conjunction by adding a reference to y to it like this:

```
   Q=: 2 : 'u S I. n = u P y'
   + Q 2 i.30
19 10 1
28 10 1
29 11 2
```